# React Typescript error "TypeError: ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.commonSortTitles is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am writing a web app using React with Typescript. I recently started some refactoring of old code to clean things up, and recieved this error:

`TypeError: ___WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.commonSortTitles is undefined`

This is the code that causes the error:

```js
Bags.ts
-------------------------------------------
import { Bag, commonSortTitles } from '..';

// code here that does not affect the issue

export const bagSortTitles = [
  ...commonSortTitles,
  '# of Magic Items',
  '# of Items'
] as const;
```

And the export commonSortTitles is here:

```js
common.ts
-------------------------------------------------------------------
export type SortDirection = typeof ascendingTitles[number];

export const commonSortTitles = [
  'Created',
  'Last Updated',
  'Weight',
  'Title'
] as const;

export const ascendingTitles = ['Ascending', 'Descending'] as const;
```

In this setup, the IDE correctly reports: [Image of what the intellisense shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWb1P.png)

Interestingly, if I move the commonSortTitles to the Bags.ts file, it begins working fine.

```js
Bags.ts (workaround)
-------------------------------------------
import { Bag } from '..';

// code here that does not affect the issue

const commonSortTitles = [
  'Created',
  'Last Updated',
  'Weight',
  'Title'
] as const;

export const bagSortTitles = [
  ...commonSortTitles,
  '# of Magic Items',
  '# of Items'
] as const;
```

This, however, means I have to duplicate the code for commonSortTitles in at least one other file, which I am working to avoid.

Here is my package.json file:

```json
package.json
---------------------------------------------------------
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.7",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.12",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.13",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^32.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-no-null": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "react-lorem-ipsum": "^1.4.9"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what it is that might be causing this? It feels to me like this might be an issue with the React version, but I can't fathom why it hasn't come up until just now (since all of this code was in the project previously, I just moved some things around)

EDIT:
Here is the index.ts for the folder these files are in '/components':

```js
/components/index.ts
-------------------------
export * from './common';
export * from './Bags';
// additional exports that are unrelated
```

And here is the index file from the parent folder to that one:

```js
index.ts
-----------------------------
export * from './components';
export * from './models';
export * from './redux';
```

Bypassing the index by directly importing from ./common.ts does indeed stop the error from occurring. Importing from '.' also works. Is there an issue with my import strategy?

Comment: Need more details. Importing from `'..'` implies an `..\index.ts` file that is not shown and likely relevant since it must be re-exporting the exports of `common.ts`

Comment: I added the requested index files (one for the folder Bags.ts and common.ts are in), as well as the parent folder.

Comment: That's weird. It should work as it is. My instinct is that this is some kind of circular dependency or import order related bug. It's definitely a bug of some sort